# New to python, trying to understand why this is happening

Tags: python

Given:

```
import argparse
parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", type=str.lower, nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

if 'test1' in args.test:
    my_test = 'Test1'
    print("Testing", my_test)
if 'test2' in args.test:
    my_test = 'Test2'
    print("Testing", my_test)
else:
    print("Invalid test defined:", args.test)
```

Why does "my_test.py -t test1" result in:

```
Testing Test1
Invalid test defined: ['test1']
```

A valid result, but with an error

But "my_test.py -t test1 test2" works as expected:

```
Testing Test1
Testing Test2
```

Comment: The first `if` is independent of the second `if..else`. Perhaps you want `if..elif..else`?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the program should do. Your else-clause is for the Test2 case. The Test1 case has no else clause. Your code checks for test1 and for test2 but when test2 doesn't exist, it goes into the else clause.
As I don't know your requirement, you could easily solve this with an else if for test2 clause.

Answer (score 0):

Ah thanks!  You pointed me in the right direction, but if--elif didn't work as it would only run the first match.  My solution:

```
    TESTS = ['test1','test2']

    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--test", type=str.lower, nargs='+')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.test:
      for my_test in sorted(args.test):
        if my_test in sorted(TESTS):
          print("Testing", my_test)
        else:
          print("Invalid test defined:", my_test)
```

gives:

```
    python3 ./test -t test2
        Testing test2

    python3 ./test -t test2 test1
        Testing test2
        Testing test1

    python3 ./test -t test2 test1 notest
        Invalid test defined: notest
        Testing test1
        Testing test2
```